# How to instrument Prometheus metrics to ServiceStack App

Tags: prometheus, servicestack

I was able to configure and get Prometheus metrics data by following this link for .net core application.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/instrumenting-asp-net-core-application-for-exporting-metrics-to-prometheus/

[image]

But when I am trying to do the same for a ServiceStack app, the /metrics endpoint is getting CORS error. Is there anything else that needs to configure for ServiceStack App?

Seems this might not be the correct way to instrument with the ServiceStack app. Any suggestion?

Also getting error if try to start server: [image]

Comment: This is working if I run VS as Admin and use the assigned port for the URL which is http://localhost:1234/metrics in this case.

Comment: app.UseHttpMetrics() seems not working as not getting the metrics.